# Enumerating resources with Jersey

Tags: java, security, rest, jersey

I use Jersey 1.17 to provide REST web services.

I know Jersey "knows" what all the resources are, so is there a way to ask Jersey to give me a full list of resources it has discovered?

Background: I would like to build in the ability for users to configure users/permissions at the resource level. To do this I would like enumerate all the resources that Jersey has discovered to populate a UI for users to setup security to users. Then I would persist a user/URL permission in a database.

**Solution**

```
static class ResourceListBuilder
{
    private List<ResourceInfo> resourceInfos = new ArrayList<ResourceInfo>();

    public List<ResourceInfo> getResourceInfos()
    {
        return resourceInfos;
    }

    private void build( Application application )
    {
        for ( Class<?> aClass : application.getClasses() )
        {
            if ( isAnnotatedResourceClass( aClass ) )
            {
                AbstractResource resource = IntrospectionModeller.createResource( aClass );

                buildResource( resource, resource.getPath().getValue() );
            }
        }
    }

    private void buildResource( AbstractResource resource, String uriPrefix )
    {
        for ( AbstractSubResourceMethod srm : resource.getSubResourceMethods() )
        {
            String uri = uriPrefix + srm.getPath().getValue();

            resourceInfos.add( new ResourceInfo( uri, srm.getHttpMethod(), srm.getMethod().getName() ) );
        }

        for ( AbstractResourceMethod srm : resource.getResourceMethods() )
        {
            resourceInfos.add( new ResourceInfo( uriPrefix, srm.getHttpMethod(), srm.getMethod().getName() ) );
        }

        for ( AbstractSubResourceLocator locator : resource.getSubResourceLocators() )
        {
            AbstractResource locatorResource = IntrospectionModeller.createResource( locator.getMethod().getReturnType() );
            buildResource( locatorResource, uriPrefix + locator.getPath().getValue() );
        }
    }

    private boolean isAnnotatedResourceClass( Class rc )
    {
        if ( rc.isAnnotationPresent( Path.class ) )
        {
            return true;
        }

        for ( Class i : rc.getInterfaces() )
        {
            if ( i.isAnnotationPresent( Path.class ) )
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}

static class ResourceInfo
{
    private String url;
    private String method;
    private String description;

    ResourceInfo( String url, String method, String description )
    {
        this.url = url;
        this.method = method;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getUrl()
    {
        return url;
    }

    public String getMethod()
    {
        return method;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fine solution proposed [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jersey-listing-all-resources) using Jersy [IntrospectionModeller](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/model/IntrospectionModeller.java).

Solution shows how to develop service for listing all deployed resources that can be called with cURL command.

Comment: Thanks that worked. However the linked solution posted is missing handling sub resource locators. I have posted my full solution